# Exception while converting string to datetime in python on GAE with timezone?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime

I am getting this exception

```
time data did not match format:  data=19:51:06 Jan 17, 2011 PST  fmt=%H:%M:%S %b %d, %Y %Z
```

for following code

```
datetime.strptime(parameters['19:51:06 Jan 17, 2011 PST'], "%H:%M:%S %b %d, %Y %Z")
```

in python code running on Google app engine.

How to modify the formatter so that it works?

Answer (score 0):

Look for the python docs for datetime.strptime [1]. They say it uses time.strptime internally, so let's check there [2].

> Support for the %Z directive is based
>   on the values contained in tzname and
>   whether daylight is true. Because of
>   this, it is platform-specific except
>   for recognizing UTC and GMT which are
>   always known (and are considered to be
>   non-daylight savings timezones).

You should go and check out the excellent pytz library [3].

[1] http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

[2] http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime

[3] http://pytz.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I am curious to know why its not working on appengine, Thx for the documentation links.

Comment: I didn't make myself clear then: platform-specific behaviour of strptime means that apparently GAE doesn't know about the time zone you're interested in. GAE implements fair parts of Python's stdlib. It's official docs are valid source of reference - GAE or not.